# Quarkus: Programatically set a config property

Tags: quarkus, eclipse-microprofile-config, quarkus-native

I have a requirement to set a property in my Quarkus app, whereby the value of this property (a quarkus-vault property) needs to read from a file. For example, in the microprofile-config.properties file, this would be an example of such property:

`myProperty.val=<value_from_a_file>`

One thing I have tried is to create a `ConfigSource`, which by creating a hashmap and setting the property there, it works fine. I referred to this web page:

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support

Here is an example of the ConfigSource implementation:

```
public class SampleConfigSource implements ConfigSource {

private static final Map<String, String> configuration = new HashMap<>();
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleConfigSource.class);
private static final String secretFilePath = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("application.vault.secret.file", String.class);

static {
    try {
        // read the value from the file and put it in the configuration map
        final String content = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(secretFilePath)).get(0);
        configuration.put("quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id", content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Override
public Set<String> getPropertyNames() {
    return configuration.keySet();
}

@Override
public String getValue(String s) {
    return configuration.get(s);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return SampleConfigSource.class.getName();
}
```

}

src/main/resources/META-INF/Services/org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource

```
com.example.config.SampleConfigSource
```

src/main/resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties

```
 ....
 application.vault.secret.file=external/secret.txt
 quarkus.vault.connect-timeout=30S
 quarkus.vault.read-timeout=30S
 quarkus.vault.url=https://prod-vault
 quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.role-id=abcde
 ....
```

Now the problem is that the `microprofile-config.properties` has the main properties for setting up vault. It also requires the `quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id` property as well, but because I'm reading this value from a file, I've added it to the `SampleConfigSource` class. I would have thought that the property would have initialised fine on bootup, but instead I get the following stack trace error:

```
15:37:05 ERROR [io.quarkus.runtime.Application] Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unknown authType null
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager.login(VaultAuthManager.java:165)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager.vaultLogin(VaultAuthManager.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager.login(VaultAuthManager.java:116)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager_Subclass.login$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager_Subclass$$function$$4.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager_Subclass.login(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager.login(VaultAuthManager.java:95)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager.getClientToken(VaultAuthManager.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager_Subclass.getClientToken$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager_Subclass$$function$$10.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultAuthManager_Subclass.getClientToken(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultKvManager.readSecret(VaultKvManager.java:36)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultKvManager_Subclass.readSecret$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultKvManager_Subclass$$function$$4.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultKvManager_Subclass.readSecret(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.VaultKvManager_ClientProxy.readSecret(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecrets(VaultConfigSource.java:131)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.lambda$fetchSecrets$2(VaultConfigSource.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecrets(VaultConfigSource.java:127)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.lambda$fetchSecrets$0(VaultConfigSource.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecrets(VaultConfigSource.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecretsFirstTime(VaultConfigSource.java:103)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.getSecretConfig(VaultConfigSource.java:81)
    at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.getValue(VaultConfigSource.java:62)
    at io.smallrye.config.ConfigValueConfigSourceWrapper.getConfigValue(ConfigValueConfigSourceWrapper.java:20)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSources.getValue(SmallRyeConfigSources.java:29)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
    at io.smallrye.config.SecretKeysConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(SecretKeysConfigSourceInterceptor.java:22)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
    at io.smallrye.config.FallbackConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(FallbackConfigSourceInterceptor.java:24)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
    at io.smallrye.config.RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.java:29)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
    at io.smallrye.config.RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.java:29)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
    at io.smallrye.config.ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.convertProfile(ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.java:120)
    at io.smallrye.config.ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.<init>(ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.java:44)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder$1.getInterceptor(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:180)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder$InterceptorWithPriority.getInterceptor(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:473)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig$ConfigSources.<init>(SmallRyeConfig.java:522)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.<init>(SmallRyeConfig.java:66)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:419)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config.readConfig(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.RuntimeConfigSetup.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:104)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

If I put the `quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id` property inside the microprofile-config.properties file (rather than `SampleConfigSource` class and instead hard code the secret in the property rather than reading from the file, then it works perfectly fine.

If I just use the `SampleConfigSource` to read the value from the file and put it in a different property name that does not start with `quarkus.vault.*` (e.g. `application.property.key`), then the property is set correctly. It is only when I read from the file and set the value (from the file) into the `quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id` config map within my custom ConfigSource (`SampleConfigSource`) then it throws this error on startup.

It's almost like as if that `quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id` property must live in `microprofile-config.properties`, but it can't read the value from the `ConfigSource`.

Another way I did it was to update the microprofile-config.properties to include the `quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id` and set it to the property that contains the value in the file (e.g.):

`quarkus.vault.authentication.app-role.secret-id=${app.value.read.from.file}`

where `app.value.read.from file` is in the `configurationMap` in the `SampleConfigSource` that contains the value read from the file. But that does not work either and I get the same stack trace error.

Is there any other way where I can programatically override the property (to read the value from a file)? Starting to feel like it might not be possible to do this for `quarkus.vault.*` properties but would really appreciate any insight or suggestions. Many thanks,

Comment: When you say that Quarkus breaks with your custom ConfigSource, how does it break? Also, can you show the code you've been using?

Comment: Hi @geoand I've updated my question with more detail and code. Hopefully this helps you and everyone to understand the issue? If not, please let me know and I'll try my best to elaborate. Any ideas/ advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Even thought I'm overriding an existing quarkus config in a config source, shouldn't this really work?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a sample application somewhere I can try?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to override the Ordinal (the default is 100)

```
@Override
public int getOrdinal() {
    return 275;
}
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support .